# rails as_json not encoding correctly for JSON.parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

So, I'm converting a reasonably complex object to JSON format using `object.as_json` in ruby in my view, and then parsing it on the client side using `JSON.parse()` in javascript to deserialise the object into something usable. However, the output from `as_json` seems to be using single quote marks encoded as `&quot;` as opposed to the double quotes required for JSON structure. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong with as_json?

Comment: Could you post the output of object.as_json? Maybe when your object is returning, your keys may be a combination of strings and symbols.

Comment: sure: you get ouput like `{ &quot;id&quot;=&gt;303, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot; test sequence&quot;, &quot;privacy&quot;=&gt;0, &quot;updated_at&quot;=&gt;Mon, 03 Dec 2012 21:51:39 UTC +00:00, &quot;user_id&quot;=&gt;1}`

Comment: +1 That's nice. And respect for finding solution and share it. I am new in Rails, but I am finding the lack of help by other rails developer very disappointed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, worked out what was going on: it was in fact a combination of two different issues:

Firstly, the quotes were being automatically encoded by rails (to prevent XSS and similar). This can be escaped by using the `html_safe` method or the `raw` function (this can introduce XSS vulnerabilities, though, so use with care).

Secondly, I was using `as_json` instead of `to_json`. Converting an ActiveSupport object to JSON in rails requires two seperate operations: rendering the object into a structure which can be serialised to JSON, and then actually serialising the object. `to_json` does both, but `as_json` only does the first. This explains why I was getting `=&gt` in my output.